# Laravel group By one type of a column and also order By only that type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is my foo table :

```
----------------------------
id | name | type | parent_id
----------------------------
 1    a   |  foo |   null
 2    b   |  bar |    1
 3    c   |  baz |    1
 4    d   |  foo |    1
 5    e   |  baz |    1
 6    f   |  bar |    1
 7    f   |  baz |    1
```

and this is the Model associated with this table :

```
class Foo extends Model {

    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Foo ::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Foo ::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

in my controller :

```
$foo = Foo::find(1);
```

and my question is how can i get all childs of  `$foo` model ordered and grouped only by baz part of type column. something like this table :

---

```
id | name | type | parent_id
----------------------------
 5    e   |  baz |    1
 7    f   |  baz |    1
 3    c   |  baz |    1
 1    a   |  foo |   null
 2    b   |  bar |    1
 4    d   |  foo |    1
 6    f   |  bar |    1
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about anything non-sql related until I had a working query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
orderByRaw("FIELD(name, 'Baz') ASC");
```